# Trouble filtering by date

Tags: r

I am summing up some values on a data frame, which works fine, until i apply a restriction with dates. I have tried declaring my "z" column of dates as follows:

```
Table$z <- as.Date(Table$createtime, "%m/%d/%Y",tz = "GMT")
```

and my End date as:

```
EndDate <- as.Date('2017-02-01')
```

These then are used in:

```
malone <- tbl_df(Table)
malone1 <- malone%>%
group_by(InstallationDate)%>%
summarize(Amount = sum(USAmount), count = n(), filter(z < EndDate))
```

Unfortunately i am not able to make this work and i am getting the following error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: difficult without reproducible example but you can try `malone%>%
filter(z < EndDate) %>%
group_by(InstallationDate)%>%
summarize(Amount = sum(USAmount), count = n())`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion and i am still getting the same error.  Since the command works find without the date filtering, it must have something to do with the formats of the dates

Comment: can you add `head(dput(malone))` in the post?

Comment: Hi Ronak. Again many thanks for all of your help. I have used the as.Date function and formatted both dates, again which did the trick.